# Find and Post in table using php

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload data to a existing User database I have stored online. I need to post the user phone number **string** in the user specified row. Using android and php, is there any way to post extra info in an existing row?

I think I'm not choosing WHERE to put that extra info.

```
<?php

require "indioPhP.php";

$username = $_POST["username"];
$phoneNumber = $_POST["phoneNumber"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$sql ="insert into User values('$phoneNumber')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo "Gracias por registrarte!";
} else{
 echo "error in insertion".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: well yes... but we can't find out what your Problem is, with your description. Is there already a column for the new phonenumber ?

Comment: yes @DoktorOSwaldo there is a new column in the User Table. Now I'm trying to look for that user giving to the php the username and posting the phone number. Is this the way to do it? thanks

Comment: and you have a working SQL Connection ? then it's a Basic SQL Update Query. If not you have to create a webservice

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I'm editing the post to show you what I'm doing, i think something is missing. Im pretty new with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now i see your Problem:

```
Update User set phonenumber=? where username=?
```

You Need something like this ? it's only one query where you search the user and Change it. Try to read more about SQL. Your code Looks a bit confused, with prepared Statements and normal statments in the same block.

**Edit**:

The statement `insert` adds a new line in the table wheras `update` modifies an existing one. Assuming your table `User` has 4 columns: username, firstname, lastname, phonenumber, for `insert`, the syntax is either

```
insert into user values("jdoe", "John", "Doe", "555 7565")
```

or

```
insert into user(username, phonenumber) values ("jdoe", "555 7565")
```

In the first case, as columns are not specified, you must give all of them.

In the second case, you insert a new line specifying only some columns. The other ones will take their default values. If a missing column doesn't have a default value, you will have an error.